# ¿Cómo exportar datos de jqgrid a Excel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, excel, jqgrid

Si tengo una `jqGrid` con información cargada, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que al dar click en un botón me exporte dichos datos a `Excel`? teniendo en cuenta que uso `SQL Server` y `ASP.net`

Con la siguiente función logro tomar los datos, pero me los carga todos en una misma celda de `Excel`, necesito que se ordene en forma de tabla, alguien puede ayudarme?

```
function exportGrid(gridID, filename) {
        alert("primero");
        var grid = $('#' + gridID);
        var rowIDList = grid.getDataIDs();
        var row = grid.getRowData(rowIDList[0]);
        var colNames = [];
        var i = 0;
        for (var cName in row) {
            colNames[i++] = cName; // Capture Column Names
        }
        alert("segundo");
        var html = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < rowIDList.length; j++) {
            row = grid.getRowData(rowIDList[j]); // Get Each Row
            for (var i = 0 ; i < colNames.length ; i++) {
                html += row[colNames[i]] + ';'; // Create a CSV delimited with ;
            }
            html += '\n';
        }
        html += '\n';

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.id = 'ExcelDL';
        a.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + html;
        a.download = filename ? filename + ".xls" : 'DataList.xls';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click(); // Downloads the excel document
        document.getElementById('ExcelDL').remove();

    }
```

Comment: No puedes generar el excel desde el cliente, deberias enviar o tener los datos en el servido, genera el documento alli y luego enviarlo al cliente para su descarga Si usaras la libreria que se integra a asp.net veras que la exportacion la realiza del lado del servidor [Excel export - jqGrid](http://www.trirand.net/examples/grid/exporting/excel/default.aspx) quizas si en tu caso usas el componente free no puedas aplicar lo mismo, pero la idea si es la misma, los datos debes tenerlos en el servidor para poder generar el excel y luego lo envias al cliente en el Response O quizas usando un handler

Comment: lo he intentado, uno de esos tutoriales hace referencia a unos archivos js que no aparecen para descargar y he intentado de otras maneras, pero me carga toda la información en una sola celda de nuevo :/

Comment: cual tutorial te refieres que tiene este js que noa parece ? lo que recomendaria es que sea el segundo link al cual deberias analizar. Sigo pensando que el excel lo debes generar en el servidor no importa la tecnica lo primero es que debes definir es que el archivos se genera en el servidor y se envia al cliente

Comment: Si, en ese mismo link, hacen referencia a unos archivos .js para poder facilitar el manejo de los datos, esa función que debe estar en esos archivos es sobre la que tengo dudas, ya que se supone es donde se toman los datos mostrados en la jqGrid, o estoy entendiendo mal?


To add the "Export to Excel" functionality to your app, first, you need to add 5 files to your project. The attached "jqGridExport.zip" file contains the current versions of these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno en este caso si alguien llega a necesitarlo utilice el siguiente código desde el archivo aspx.cs:

```
protected void btnDescargaMasiva_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var dt = sc.GetAll(_paisE);

        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();

        context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
        context.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= Datos Maestros - " + _paisE + ".csv");

        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            context.Response.Write(c.ColumnName + ";");
        }
        context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                context.Response.Write(r[i].ToString().Replace(";", string.Empty) + ";");
            }
            context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        context.Response.End();
    }
```

En donde al obtener los datos en una DataTable se puede exportar el archivo fácilmente a excel, asignando el nombre que deseamos y con un formato que reconoce los caracteres como la 'ñ' y la tilde.